# Exclude key from reduce in Couchbase map/reduce views

Tags: couchbase, nosql

Is there a way to not include results in the reduce view when certain conditions are not met (e.g. the sum or count is zero)?

My scenario is a bit complex but for simplicity, let's say we have flight reservations coming in as documents. I also have flight schedule with available seats in the same bucket. My map function looks something like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (meta.id.match(/^flight./)) {
    emit([doc.flighno, doc.schedule], {"availableSeats", doc.availableSeats});
  }
  else if (meta.id.match(/^request\./) && doc.status = "pending") {
    emit([doc.flighno, doc.schedule], {"requestedSeats", doc.requestedSeats});
  }
}
```

The map function will then emit these rows (I'm using this human readable format for `schedule` just to make it easier to read.):

```
"rows"=:[
{"id":"flight.123456", "key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":20}},
{"id":"request.1001",  "key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":2} },
{"id":"request.1002",  "key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":3} },
{"id":"request.1003",  "key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":5} },
{"id":"flight.654321", "key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":50}},
{"id":"request.2001",  "key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":5} },
{"id":"request.2002",  "key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":25}},
{"id":"request.2003",  "key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":35}},
{"id":"flight.999999", "key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":0} },
{"id":"request.3001",  "key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":5} },
{"id":"request.3002",  "key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":15}},
{"id":"request.3003",  "key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":35}},
{"id":"flight.888888", "key":["AC124","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":45}},
{"id":"flight.777777", "key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":40}},
{"id":"request.4001",  "key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":10}},
{"id":"request.4002",  "key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":10}},
{"id":"request.4003",  "key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"requestedSeats":20}}
]
```

In my case, I would like to have a reduce function that aggregates the flight documents together with the sum of the available seats within the request documents. The far I could get was this:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  var result = {availableSeats: 0, waiting: 0, toProcess: false};
  for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].availableSeats > 0) {
      result.availableSeats += values[i].availableSeats;
    }
    if (values[i].requestedSeats > 0) {
      result.requestedSeats += values[i].requestedSeats;
    }
  }
  result.toProcess = Math.min(result.availableSeats, result.requestedSeats) > 0;
  return result;
}
```

The result from the reduced view would be:

```
"rows"=:[
{"key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":20, "requestedSeats": 10, "toProcess": true}},
{"key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":50, "requestedSeats": 60, "toProcess": true}},
{"key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":0,  "requestedSeats": 55, "toProcess": false}},
{"key":["AC124","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":45, "requestedSeats": 0,  "toProcess": false}},
{"key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":40, "requestedSeats": 40, "toProcess": true}}
]
```

But, essentially, what I need is to have a view that contains only the keys where both the `availableSeats` and `requestedSeats` are positive, i.e. `toProcess` flag is true. Most of my results, will have one of those values as zero, so, there is nothing to do with them, loading the entire view (that will always grow), is not ideal.

Any suggestions?

**Update**:

I tried to do:

```
if (result.tbd) {
  return(result);
}
else {
  return null;
}
```

and also

```
if (result.tbd) {
  return(result);
}
else {
  return {};
}
```

The keys that I don't want still showing up, except that the values are `null` or `{}`, like this:

```
"rows"=:[
{"key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":20, "requestedSeats": 10, "toProcess": true}},
{"key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":50, "requestedSeats": 60, "toProcess": true}},
{"key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":null},
{"key":["AC124","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":null},
{"key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":40, "requestedSeats": 40, "toProcess": true}}
]
```

or

```
"rows"=:[
{"key":["AC783","2016-05-04UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":20, "requestedSeats": 10, "toProcess": true}},
{"key":["AC783","2016-05-11UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":50, "requestedSeats": 60, "toProcess": true}},
{"key":["AC123","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{}},
{"key":["AC124","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{}},
{"key":["AC125","2016-05-13UTC"], "value":{"availableSeats":40, "requestedSeats": 40, "toProcess": true}}
]
```

This is not too different than what I got at first as the number of rows with such keys will grow a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're already halfway there. You just need to check the `toProcess` flag and return an empty result `{availableSeats: 0, waiting: 0, toProcess: false}` if it's false instead of the actual values you calculated. That way the results you don't want will not be propagated to the rereduce step and will not be counted.

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty result'? I tried `return {};` and also `return null` but no luck, the undesired keys still showing up. I also tried to omit the `return` clause, which doesn't look right, but I tried anyway, and I think it broke the view completely. I will update my question soon to reflect what I just described. Thx.

Comment: I just updated my question. Is that what you meant by "return an empty result"?